# How to convert String to JsonArray?

Tags: java, android, json, string

I am trying to manipulate a JsonArray to look like another JsonArray.
I implemented some string methods to the existing JsonArray. and now I want to put it back in another JsonArray.

**CODE**

```
                Log.d("defaultArrayShuffled", defaultArray.toString());

                String temp = defaultArray.toString();
                String temp1= temp.replaceAll("_white_", "_");
                Log.d("temp1", temp1);

                JSONObject temp2 = new JSONObject();
                temp2.put("arr", temp1);
                Log.d("temp2", temp2.toString());
                replacingArray = temp2.getJSONArray("arr");
```

**LogCAT**

```
07-03 19:16:37.310: D/defaultArrayShuffled(8863): ["findhidden\/o_white_64.png","findhidden\/x_white_64.png","findhidden\/f_white_64.png","findhidden\/b_white_64.png","findhidden\/a_white_64.png","findhidden\/g_white_64.png","findhidden\/p_white_64.png","findhidden\/u_white_64.png","findhidden\/n_white_64.png","findhidden\/j_white_64.png","findhidden\/y_white_64.png","findhidden\/q_white_64.png","findhidden\/l_white_64.png","findhidden\/t_white_64.png","findhidden\/h_white_64.png","findhidden\/v_white_64.png","findhidden\/r_white_64.png","findhidden\/k_white_64.png","findhidden\/m_white_64.png","findhidden\/c_white_64.png","findhidden\/z_white_64.png","findhidden\/s_white_64.png","findhidden\/w_white_64.png","findhidden\/d_white_64.png","findhidden\/i_white_64.png","findhidden\/e_white_64.png"]
07-03 19:16:37.310: D/temp1(8863): ["findhidden\/o_64.png","findhidden\/x_64.png","findhidden\/f_64.png","findhidden\/b_64.png","findhidden\/a_64.png","findhidden\/g_64.png","findhidden\/p_64.png","findhidden\/u_64.png","findhidden\/n_64.png","findhidden\/j_64.png","findhidden\/y_64.png","findhidden\/q_64.png","findhidden\/l_64.png","findhidden\/t_64.png","findhidden\/h_64.png","findhidden\/v_64.png","findhidden\/r_64.png","findhidden\/k_64.png","findhidden\/m_64.png","findhidden\/c_64.png","findhidden\/z_64.png","findhidden\/s_64.png","findhidden\/w_64.png","findhidden\/d_64.png","findhidden\/i_64.png","findhidden\/e_64.png"]
07-03 19:16:37.310: D/temp2(8863): {"arr":"[\"findhidden\\\/o_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/x_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/f_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/b_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/a_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/g_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/p_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/u_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/n_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/j_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/y_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/q_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/l_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/t_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/h_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/v_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/r_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/k_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/m_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/c_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/z_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/s_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/w_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/d_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/i_64.png\",\"findhidden\\\/e_64.png\"]"}
```

**MORE LOGCAT**

```
07-03 19:16:37.320: W/System.err(8863):     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96)
```

Comment: I will be able to reply after 12 hrs... offline for now... thanks

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: How to convert String to JsonArray ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the log output of temp2, the json type of arr is String. So you would get typeMismatch if you try to get JSONArray out of it.

See if the below code works for you. JSONObject's constructor can take a JSON-encoded string containing an object. So we use it to create temp2.

```
Log.d("defaultArrayShuffled", defaultArray.toString());

String temp = defaultArray.toString();
String temp1= temp.replaceAll("_white_", "_");
Log.d("temp1", temp1);

JSONObject temp2 = new JSONObject("{ \"arr\" : " + temp1 + "}");
//temp2.put("arr", temp1);
Log.d("temp2", temp2.toString());
replacingArray = temp2.getJSONArray("arr");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: perfect... just replaced the code and it worked :O thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Several ideas - 
A. I find Jackson to be a better Json library. Consider using it. It provides better error messages 
B. I wrote the following code , similar to what you did using an infra we did at [www.ovirt.org](http://www.ovirt.org)  for Json serializing and Deserializing:

```
 String[] arr = { "aaa_white_.png", "bbb_white_.png", "ccc_white_.png", "ddd.png" };
        JsonObjectSerializer serialezer = new JsonObjectSerializer();
        String payload = serialezer.serialize(arr);
        String newPayload = payload.replaceAll("_white_", "_");
        JsonObjectDeserializer der = new JsonObjectDeserializer();
        String[] res = (String[]) der.deserialize(newPayload, String[].class);
        System.out.println(payload);
        System.out.println(res);
        for (String str : res) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

You can git clone our code, and you should look at `ovirt-engine/backend/manager/modules/utils/src/main/java/org/ovirt/engine/core/utils/serialization/json` 
To see what we did there.